# technical advantages of dynamoDB over mongoDB: considering migration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I currently have a website built using node connected to a mongoDB free tier cluster. As I'm looking to deploy my website to production, I was wondering if dynanmoDB provides any sort of technical advantages that would make it worth rewriting all my queries in node to migrate my DB (doesn't contain much data) to a dynamoDB. I'm considering this since I feel like the dynamoDB will integrate well with my web deployed on EC2 and also since AWS gives a free tier promotion.
Is there really a difference? or should I just purchase a mongoDB cluster? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel this really depends on use cases but having used both of these here are my personal takes.

DynamoDb is like a dragster - its not very flexible in what it can do but my god it's fast. What I like about it is that it forces you to think in terms of performance and you can do quite a bit with it with a little rethinking.

MongoDb is a Swiss army tool and can do pretty much anything but the flexibility is a double sided sword. - it's really easy to create queries that do not scale well so you really have to be on top if it.

So if your data is relatively simple, you have a lot of it, want speed - DynamoDb.
If you need complex aggregation, geospatial calculations, etc and are satisfied with the performance for your data size then MongoDb.

I love both of these tools though DynamoDb is my new favorite. I appreciate it's design and the way it makes me rethink my schema.